# Oracle Merge into ... When not matched insert ... - Can i use Alias

Tags: sql, oracle

Here a simplified table example:

```
MAGIC_TABLE
titi | tata
-----------
val1 | magic1
val2 | magic2
val3 | magic1
val4 | magic1
val5 | magic2
```

What I want to achieve is that ->

For every row that have `tata = 'magic2'` and some value in `titi` if it does not exist a `'magic1'` row with **the same titi value** then I should add a row with `titi.value` and `'magic1'`

Here is a simplified version of my SQL oracle query that I am working on :

```
merge into MAGIC_TABLE magic
using (
    with UNMAGIC_TABLE as (
        select titi, tata from MAGIC_TABLE
        and tata='magic1'
    )
    SELECT titi, tata from UNMAGIC_TABLE 
) really_unmagic
on 
(
  magic.titi = really_unmagic.titi
  magic.tata = really_unmagic.tata
  and magic.tata='magic2'
) 
when not matched then insert (titi, tata) 
values 
(magic.titi, 'magic1');
```

Somehow I keep getting this error :

**ORA-38101: Invalid column in the INSERT VALUES Clause: "MAGIC"."TITI"**

So I was wondering if it is a syntax issue around aliases? What did I do wrong there ?

**EDIT** : It's an inattention error, as  George Joseph  pointed out I have to use `unreally_magic` to make it work, since when it's not matched I do not have lines from `magic`

Comment: WHEN NOT MATCHED would imply you want to INSERT into the magic table with values from USING clause and thereforeyou would need to make use of really_unmagic.titi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd write that merge statement like so:

```
MERGE INTO magic_table tgt
USING (SELECT titi,
              'magic1' tata
       FROM   magic_table
       WHERE  tata = 'magic2') src
  ON (tgt.titi = src.titi AND tgt.tata = src.tata)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (tgt.titi,
          tgt.tata)
  VALUES (src.titi,
          src.tata);
```

Comment: Any reason not to go slightly further to `AND tgt.tata = src.tata`?

Comment: probably not in this instance; I just had in the back of my mind that if something was being updated you can't update things that are in the `on` clause. I've just done a test, and even in this case you couldn't update the tgt.tata column, even if you wanted to. I've updated my answer to include your very good point! *{:-)

Comment: How did you manage to get that hat in what looks like the most appropriate place and angle?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I used the widget in the winter bash pop-up to do it; it can resize and rotate the hat. There's a "show controls" option that brings it up if you tick it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but it seems I had to use `really_unmagic` to make it work, so I also had to change both `where` clause to have the correct wanted data in `values`.
But I still have no idea why the first query would not work.

```
merge into MAGIC_TABLE magic
using (
    with UNMAGIC_TABLE as (
        select titi, tata from MAGIC_TABLE
        and tata='magic2'
    )
    SELECT titi, tata from UNMAGIC_TABLE 
) really_unmagic
on 
(
  magic.titi = really_unmagic.titi
  magic.tata = really_unmagic.tata
  and magic.tata='magic1'
) 
when not matched then insert (titi, tata) 
values 
(really_unmagic.titi, 'magic1');
```

Comment: From the logic being used i suspect you would want to make use of MERGE. 

You are insert records called magic1 for those records where (titi,tata) has an exsiting "magic1" value but doenst have "magic2" value?

Comment: Can you tell what is your goal here

Comment: I want to insert rows following this example: I have a value pair ("Zeus", "magic2"), but I do not have a pair ("Zeus","magic1"). So I want to add a new row with a pair ("Zeus", "magic1")

Comment: This is why I tend to use the aliases "tgt" (for the table you are merging into) and "src" (for the table/subquery you are using for the source data) when I write MERGE statements - it's much easier (IMO) to think in terms of "this is my source data, and I want to update the target table", which makes it easier to work out what to put in the update and insert sections. YMMV, of course!